# copy min columns of 2d array to 1d array java

Tags: java, arrays, min

I want to create a 1D array that saves the min columns from my 2D array, but I get wrong the min values. My theseisLine array is a copy from my intP array that I store there the column numbers, so theseisLine shows the min from each column.

```
package themab2018;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class THEMAB2018 {

static void displayP(int intP[][]) {
        System.out.println("intP2D");
        for(int i = 0; i < intP.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < intP[i].length; j++) 
                System.out.print(intP[i][j] + " ");
                System.out.println();

        }           
    }

static void findMinCol(int intP[][] ,int n) {

    int theseisLine[] = new int[n];

    if(theseisLine.length < intP.length)
        for(int i = 0; i < theseisLine.length; i++)
            theseisLine[i] = intP[0][i];
    else
        for(int i = 0; i < intP.length; i++)
            theseisLine[i] = intP[0][i];

    int min = theseisLine[0];
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Min Array");

    for(int i = 0; i < theseisLine.length; i++) {

        if(theseisLine[i] < min) {
            min = theseisLine[i];

        }
        System.out.print(min + " ");
    }

}
public static void main(String[] args){

    int m , n;

    System.out.println("Import m , n");
    do {
        System.out.print("Give m ");
        m = scannerUserInput.getInteger();
        System.out.print("Give n ");
        n = scannerUserInput.getInteger();

    } while (m < 1 && n < 1);

    int intP2D[][] = new int [m][n];
    int theseisLine[] = new int[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < intP2D.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < intP2D[i].length; j++) {
            intP2D[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * (10 - 1)+1)+1;
        }
    }

    displayP(intP2D);
    findMinCol(intP2D, m);                  
}    
}
```

**The result that I get example :**

```
Import m , n                                         
Give m 3
Give n 4

intP2D
3 9 7 2 
8 9 7 6 
5 8 8 7 

Min Array
3 3 3
```

**The result that i want in this example :**

```
Import m , n
Give m 3
Give n 4

intP2D
3 9 7 2 
8 9 7 6 
5 8 8 7 

Min Array
3 8 7 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, while calling findMinCol(intP2D, m); you need to pass the count of column i.e. n and not count of row.

Secondly, while calculating the min element in the column, you are comparing all element with int min = theseisLine[0]; which might not be correct.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class THEMAB2018 {

    static void displayP(int intP[][]) {
        System.out.println("intP2D");
        for(int i = 0; i < intP.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < intP[i].length; j++)
                System.out.print(intP[i][j] + " ");
            System.out.println();

        }
    }

    static void findMinCol(int intP[][] ,int n) {

        int theseisLine[] = new int[n];

        for(int i = 0; i < theseisLine.length; i++)
            theseisLine[i] = intP[0][i];


        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Min Array");

        for(int i = 0; i < theseisLine.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < intP.length; j++) {
                if (intP[j][i] < theseisLine[i]) {
                    theseisLine[i] = intP[j][i];
                }
            }
            System.out.print(theseisLine[i] + " ");
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int m , n;

        System.out.println("Import m , n");

        m = 3; n = 4;

        int intP2D[][] = new int [m][n];
        int theseisLine[] = new int[n];

        for(int i = 0; i < intP2D.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < intP2D[i].length; j++) {
                intP2D[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * (10 - 1)+1)+1;
            }
        }

        displayP(intP2D);
        findMinCol(intP2D, **n**);
    }
}
```

the output I am getting:

```
intP2D
2 5 8 7 
10 6 9 3 
7 9 3 8 

Min Array
2 5 3 3
```

Comment: Thanks this worked i get the correct result that i want, but i cant understand that code :     for(int i = 0; i < theseisLine.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 1; j < intP.length; j++) {
                if(intP[j][i] < theseisLine[i]) {
                    theseisLine[i] = intP[j][i];               
                }
            }
            
            System.out.print(theseisLine[i] + " ");
        }

Comment: @LazosPap This piece of code iterates over the 2D array column by column and calculate the min value for the column and assign it to the theseisLine[i]. 

It starts with column 0 iterates through all row of that column, compares to find the minimum
prints the min value when the loop for all row ends. 
Then moves to column 1, so forth and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to check in your finding method with the if-else block. You don't need it anyway to find the minimum of each column, that's why I removed it. A simple nested for loop solves your problem.

Additionally, you don't need to pass the number of columns as a parameter, because it can be easily queried from the matrix. I still left it in to avoid having to change the method call.

```
static void findMinCol(int intP[][] ,int n) {
    int rows = intP.length;
    int cols = intP[0].length;
    int[] result = new int[cols];
    for(int i = 0; i < cols; i++){
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++){
            if(min > intP[j][i]){
                min = intP[j][i];
            }
        }
        result[i] = min;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(result[i] + " ");
    }        
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is an exercise for my algorithm course and i have to write it in a paper i don't know if its eligible to use matrix as you said. The findMinCol method is to find the min numbers from the columns of the 2d aray and save it in theseisLine array so i can call it and show it in my main program this was the exercise.